# JSF - Habilitar/Deshabilitar CommandLink según valor de un campo de la DB

Tags: postgresql, jsf, primefaces

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, tengo un datatable con registros sacados de mi DB (PostgreSQL), con dos opciones al momento que están con el atributo CommandLink: PDF y Editar.

Lo que deseo hacer y que hasta ahora me ha resultado nulo, es que al cargar la página, me aparezca habilitada o deshabilitada la opción de PDF según un campo de la DB que tiene su respectivo setter y getter, este campo, es de tipo INT.

Opciones de mi Datatable

[image: Opciones de mi Datatable]

Campo de mi DB que verifica el estado si ha sido descargado

[image: Campo de mi DB que verifica el estado si ha sido descargado]

Mi xhtml:

```
<p:column  style="text-align: center">
<p:commandLink ajax="false" value="PDF" class="icon-file-pdf" actionListener="#{ordenRetiroBean.exportpdf2(ord)}">
</p:commandLink>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar el atributo disabled de commandLink, en base a la propiedad de DB:

```
     <p:commandLink ajax="false" value="PDF" class="icon-file-pdf" 
                actionListener="#{ordenRetiroBean.exportpdf2(ord)}" 
                disabled="#{ordenRetiroBean.nombrePropiedad!=1}"/>
```

Así se deshabilitaría el commandLink si la propiedad nombrePropiedad del backing bean orderRetiroBean es distinta de 1.

Comment: Perfecto Pablo, me funcionó! Muchas gracias